# Are there any nontrivial, finite subrings of an infinite ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

For example, $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ where $S=\{0\}$ is the trivial subring which is finite. Is there a nontrivial subring of an infinite ring (i.e. of $\mathbb{R}$ or not) that is non-infinite?

This came up as a student question in my 3000-level abstract algebra class discussion and is not a homework problem (though I am a student).

Comment: While $\mathbb{R}$ does not contain any nontrivial finite subrings (think about addition), there are other infinite rings that contain (nontrivial) finite subrings.  Think about an infinite field with finite characteristic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A subring $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is nontrivial when it contains some $c\neq0$, and therefore it must contain infinitely many elements: 
$$\ldots,-2c,c,0,c,2c,\ldots$$
(in fact, under the [usual definition of subring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring), any subring must contain $1$, and so by the above argument any subring of $\mathbb{R}$ must already contain $\mathbb{Z}$, which is infinite. But I'm assuming you're not including this in your definition?)

However, there are many infinite rings having finite subrings. For example, let $R$ be any finite ring; then the polynomial ring $R[x]$ is infinite but has $R$ as a subring.

Comment: I agree that any subring of $\mathbb{R}$ must contain $\mathbb{Z}$ and so there are no finite nontrivial subrings $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. I just used $\mathbb{R}$ to express the trivial subring.

Answer (score 5):

Zev's argument in fact shows that there cannot be any finite subrings in a ring of characteristic zero (when subrings are required to have the same multiplicative unit), and Niel's answer shows that there can be a non-trivial finite subrng in an infinite ring.

So, for an example of a finite subring of an infinite ring, let us look at rings of positive characteristic. For example, let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be the finite field of $p$ elements. Then it is a subring of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_p(X)$, which is infinite. It is also a subring of the algebraic completion $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, which is an infinite field.

There are also infinite rings which contain no non-trivial finite subrngs: $\mathbb{Z}$ is an example, since every additive subgroup is infinite. In fact, every integral domain of non-zero characteristic cannot contain any non-trivial finite subrngs. Let $R$ be such a ring, and suppose $S$ is a non-trivial additive subgroup. Then, $S$ contains a non-zero element $x$. But $R$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}$, and $R$ is an integral domain, so for any non-zero integer $n$, $n x \ne 0$. In particular, if $n \ne m$, then $n x \ne m x$, and both are in $S$ if $n$ and $m$ are integers. So $S$ is infinite.

Answer (score 5):

As Zev points out, it's clear that $\mathbb{R}$ has no nontrivial finite subring.

On the other hand, there are also clearly *some* infinite rings that have non-trivial finite subrings -- for example $R[x]$ for any finite ring $R$, which is infinite and has $R$ itself as a subring.,

Comment: My strategy is usually to make a post quickly and edit things in later as I think of them; I didn't see you had posted the same example as an answer until I'd already added it in. You have my +1 :)

Comment: @Zev, no hard feelings, I do the same thing myself.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another simple example: ℝ × (ℤ / 2ℤ) is an infinite ring, and has a finite subring which is isomorphic to ℤ / 2ℤ which is generated by (0,1).

Comment: Depending on whether one wants the multiplicative identity of the big ring to coincide with the one of the smaller one, this might not be considered a subring...